# Пустые массивы после первого выполнения socket_select

Tags: php, сокет

Помогите разобраться в работе с сокетами через PHP. Не могу сделать сокет-сервер.
Проблема в том, что после первого выполнения `socket_select` все три массива оказываются пусты.

```
if (!$this->socketMaster = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) {
    error_log('socket_create() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    die();
}
if (!socket_bind($this->socketMaster, $this->address, $this->port)) {
    error_log('socket_bind() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    die();
}
if (!socket_listen($this->socketMaster)) {
    error_log('socket_listen() failed: ' . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
    die();
}

//помещаем мастер сокет в массив на чтение

$read = array($this->socketMaster);
$write = array();
$error = array();
$client_sockets = array();
$addressPeer = "";
while (!$this->stop_server) {
    $num_changed = socket_select($read, $write, $error, 0, 10000);
    //если что-то изменилось
    if ($num_changed) {
        if (in_array($this->socketMaster, $read)) {
            if (count($client_sockets) < $this->max_clients) {
                $socket = socket_accept($this->socketMaster);
                $client_sockets[$addressPeer] = $socket;                
            }

            // Цикл по всем сокетам с проверкой изменений в каждом из них
            foreach ($client_sockets as $addressPeer => $client) {
                //клиентский сокет передаёт данные
                    if (in_array($client, $read)) {
                        //обработка поступающих дыннах
                    }
                    if (in_array($client, $write)) {
                        //отправляем данные
                    }
                    if (in_array($client, $error)) {
                        //обработка ошибок
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $this - у вас это что за объект?

Comment: Сокет-сервер оформлен ввиде класса. Это код метода отвечающего за саму работу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение. В начале цикла надо мастер-сокет добавлять в массив на чтение

```
$read[] = $this->socketMaster;  
$read = array_merge($read, $client_sockets);
```

Вроде работает, но будут ещё вопросы.